# Conditionally buffering the processing of Observables

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I want to buffer some requests and send them in bulk, only when some condition is available (e.g. connectivity).

I was thinking that using concat would achieve waiting for the first condition, but even this does not work:

```
import { combineLatest, concat, merge, of, Subject, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { bufferTime, delay, filter, mapTo, shareReplay, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const neededValueDelay = timer(2000); // condition simulation

const pushQueue = new Subject();
const registrationQueue = concat(
  neededValueDelay,
  pushQueue.pipe(
    bufferTime(200),
    // tap(console.log), // used to debug if polling hos stopped
    filter(isNonEmptyList),
    shareReplay(1)
  )
);

neededValueDelay.subscribe(() => (neededValue = true)); // this is the condition

export function isNonEmptyList<T>(value: T[]): value is NonNullable<T[]> {
  return value.length > 0;
}

function registerTopic(topic: any): Subject<any> { // this is the fast action
  pushQueue.next(topic);
  return null;
}

function sendRequest(values: any) { // this is the buffered action
   console.log( 'request:' , neededValue , values.map(val => val.name) );
}

const subscription = registrationQueue.subscribe(values => sendRequest(values));

const example = of(null);
const message = merge(
  example.pipe(mapTo({ name: 'Topic1' })),
  example.pipe(
    mapTo({ name: 'Topic2' }),
    delay(100)
  ),
  example.pipe(
    mapTo({ name: 'Topic3' }),
    delay(110)
  ),
  example.pipe(
    mapTo({ name: 'Topic4' }),
    delay(200)
  ),
  example.pipe(
    mapTo({ name: 'Topic5' }),
    delay(400)
  )
);

message.subscribe(val => registerTopic(val));
```

I'm creating a few topics with a random delay, they should get aggregated every 2 seconds and the sendRequest() method should process the buffered array. So the response should either look like:

```
request:true Topic1,Topic2,Topic3
request:true Topic4
request:true Topic5
```

or

```
request:true Topic1,Topic2,Topic3,Topic4,Topic5
```

Ideally, the requests should be buffered while the condition switches to false, though just the initial condition (delay) is also sufficient.

I was thinking of pushing items back into the queue while the condition is unmet, but that didn't work and it's also quite silly:

```
function sendRequest(values: any[]) {
  if (!neededValue){
    values.forEach( val => registerTopic(val));
    return;
  }
...
}
```

Comment: Sounds like this is solved entirely by RxJS's Buffer Operator

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the one  you are looking for but how about [buffer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/buffer) operator.

```js
// RxJS v7+
import { timer, merge, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { buffer, mapTo, delay, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const example$ = interval(3000);
const messages$ = merge(
  example$.pipe(mapTo({ name: 'Topic1' })),
  example$.pipe(
    mapTo({ name: 'Topic2' }),
    delay(100)
  ),
  example$.pipe(
    mapTo({ name: 'Topic3' }),
    delay(110)
  ),
  example$.pipe(
    mapTo({ name: 'Topic4' }),
    delay(200)
  ),
  example$.pipe(
    mapTo({ name: 'Topic5' }),
    delay(400)
  )
);

const neededValueDelay$ = timer(5000); // condition simulation
/**
 * It will collect Observables until neededValueDelay$ emits.
 * warning: it will fire sooner if messages$ completes before neededValueDelay$
 * has a change to emit.
 */
messages$
  .pipe(
    buffer(neededValueDelay$),
    /**
     * Since I'm using interval as underlying method to emit messages$ every 3 seconds.
     * I need to make sure I'm done with that observable */
    take(1)
  )
  .subscribe(console.log, null, () => console.log('I complete'));
```

[live code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-buffering-observables?file=index.ts)

But you could also use concat and timer if that helps to your use case:

```
// RxJS v7+
import { timer, merge, concat, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { buffer, mapTo, delay, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

/** here the new operators, time and concat */
const example$ = timer(1000);
const messages$ = concat(
  example$.pipe(mapTo({ name: 'Topic1' })),
  example$.pipe(
    mapTo({ name: 'Topic2' }),
    delay(100)
  ),
  example$.pipe(
    mapTo({ name: 'Topic3' }),
    delay(110)
  ),
  example$.pipe(
    mapTo({ name: 'Topic4' }),
    delay(200)
  ),
  example$.pipe(
    mapTo({ name: 'Topic5' }),
    delay(400)
  )
);

const neededValueDelay$ = timer(5000); // condition simulation
/**
 * It will collect Observables until neededValueDelay$ emits, then completes.
 */
messages$
  .pipe(
    buffer(neededValueDelay$),
    take(1)
  )
  .subscribe(console.log, null, () => console.log('I complete'));
```

[live code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-buffering-observables-timer-concat?file=index.ts)